# Stuck with database Insertion

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I'm developing an android application where I'm Inserting values from the Server into the local database. Everytime I insert I'll check whether the same row already exists or not using some value. If already exists means I'll do the update .otherwise, Insertion.

Like the following

```
if(checkValueAlreadyInDb("SELECT * FROM User WHERE UserID='"+fieldValues
                                .getProperty("UserID").toString()+"'"))
                        {
                            updateDb("User", contentValues," UserID='"+fieldValues
                                .getProperty("UserID").toString()+"'" );

                        }
                        else
                        { 
                            insertIntoDb("User", contentValues);
                        }
```

**updateDb() function**

```
public void updateDb(String TableName, ContentValues contentValues,
            String whereClause) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = db.getWritableDatabase();
        sqLiteDatabase.update(TableName, contentValues, whereClause, null);
        Log.e("Value",db.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM User WHERE"+whereClause, null).getString(2));
        sqLiteDatabase.close();
    }
```

**insertIntoDb() function**

```
public void insertIntoDb(String TableName, ContentValues contentValues) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = db.getWritableDatabase();
        sqLiteDatabase.insert(TableName, null, contentValues);
        sqLiteDatabase.close();
    }
```

In my Database the table User is created like below,

```
DATABASE_TABLES.add("CREATE TABLE User("
              +"UserID INTEGER  NOT NULL  ,"
              +"UserName varchar(50) NULL,"
                +"Password varchar(50) NULL,"
                +"FirstName varchar(50) NULL ,"
                +"LastName varchar(50) NULL,"
                +"CompanyName varchar(50) NULL,"
                +"MobilePhone LONG NULL,"
                +"EmailAddress varchar(50) NULL,"
                +"Active BOOLEAN NULL,"
                +"ClientID INTEGER NULL,"
                +"RoleID INTEGER NULL,"
                +"ProjectID INTEGER NULL,"
                +"ProductID INTEGER NULL,"
                +"CreatedBy varchar(50) NULL,"
                +"UpdatedBy varchar(50) NULL ,"
                +"Createdtime DATE NULL ,"
                +"UpdatedTime DATE NULL,"
                +"IsDeleted BOOLEAN NULL)");
```

My problem is after inserting or updating the values , the cursor count of **User** table is zero 
if I create cursor like below

```
 database.getReadableDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM User where UserName='Rakesh' and Password='123' and Active='true'",null).getString(0);
```

and throws the exception

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 126
```

I can't realize where the mistake is happened . please give me a solution .

Comment: In which block you got Stuck.

Comment: database.getReadableDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM User where UserName='Rakesh' and Password='123' and Active='true'",null).getString(0);

Comment: don't get the String directly like that, store your query result in a cursor variable, call `cursor.moveToFirst()` and get the String..

Comment: thank you very much .. I got your point now .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way:

```
 Cursor mCursor = database.getReadableDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM User where UserName='Rakesh' and Password='123' and Active='true'",null);

  if(mCursor.getCount()>0 &&  mCursor.moveToFirst()){

  do{
   Log.d("data: ",mCursor.getString(0));

   }while(mCursor.moveToNext(););

  }
```

And make sure that you have inserted data into your Table.

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite does not support 'varchar' data type so make it text.[Sql datatypes](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)
And like others pointed,do check whether your return result, that is the cursor ,has results in it with getCount() function.To do that take result of your query into a Cursor object.Later extract the string from the cursor.You are supplying column 0 to the getString() function which is wrong.